# Showing a Barcode on a SSRS report without SSRS addins

Tags: reporting-services, barcode

I recently had the task of adding a barcode onto a SSRS report without being able to add anything to the report server other than the report itself.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898892/barcodes-and-ssrs/24037533#24037533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to render the barcode as a dynamic image on our webserver and reference the image from the report. It works beautifully. I just wanted to post a possible solution for others in the same boat.

Comment: An added benefit of this approach was that rendering the reports as PDF embeded the image into the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I like that - we installed a barcode font which worked for us.

Comment: That would work in some cases. We needed to use a 2d barcode which complicated matters.