# Barcodes and SSRS

Tags: printing, reporting-services, barcode

Good Day All,

I am trying to get barcodes to print correctly in SSRS.  I have the correct font installed on the report server and on the machine printing the report, the barcodes look correct on the screen but when you go to print the report it puts spaces in the barcodeand distorts it making it unreadable.

How can I fix this issue without a ton of coding or complex solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Two things: 1. Are the barcodes in an image in a form of png, gif, or jpg?  2. When you say print, what format?  HTML, PDF, Excel, etc..

Comment: No they are text, just using the barcode font 3 of 9.  Print off a laser printer, like a word doc.

Comment: When you say barcode font did you download a special font for SSRS?  Generally from memory SSRS does not come with barcode font and you need to set it up on the client and server as well as ensure that the box displaying it is using that font too.

Comment: Is there a special bar code font for SSRS?

Comment: Not that I know of, that is why I was asking you got that font.

Comment: It turns out the that SSRS prints the barcode as text and it needs to be printed as an image, I resolved this issue by using Crystal Reports which apparently handles barcodes without any hassles.  I found several references on how to turn SSRS text into an image, but that was just over the top in my mind.

Answer (score -1):

Following is what we are doing

1. Put `*` before and after the required text.  [Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731231/barcode-fonts-vs-barcode-printer-fonts?rq=1 ]
2. Ensure that the font required for barcode is installed in each client machine. (I have `SQL 2005 rsclientprint ActiveX 90.3282` )

Note: The Fonts are stored in "***Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Fonts***"

**References**

1. [How to Install, Manage, and Delete Fonts on Your PC](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22277/how-to-install-manage-and-delete-fonts-on-your-pc/)